# Why couldn't I get GPS coordinates in a remote place?

Tags: android, gps

I went on a trip somewhere remote and I didn't have mobile access but I thought that my GPS would work anyway since a GPS transmitter just relies on satellites. I have the following code to get GPS location:

```
mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);
```

I tried to record my GPS coordinates and they ended up empty.

Is there something that I am not doing correctly or that I don't understand?

What can I change so that my phone can record raw GPS data with or without network access?

Comment: Just wondering, where does PHP and SQL come into the equation?

Comment: Try comparing your code with the performance of some GPS application from the android market. See it works at the location you are talking about.

Comment: I had same problem and i find out we have to have data connection(Wifi or network provider ) to work gps.

Comment: Did you have access to plenty of open sky? Were you outdoors?

Comment: @Jared Farrish, my mistake. I deleted a question I had earlier and posted this one. Akki: Hmm, any way to get this to work without a data connection? I have not had any luck, but I don't know if it is impossible.

Comment: @David Schwartz yeah, but maybe I did not wait long enough. I read somewhere that gps (some random gps, not the one on the phone) can take up to 5 minutes to get your location

Comment: @SpeedBirdNine it seems all the GPS application from the market require some kind of data connection. I would like to be able to get gps data without a data connection. Do you know of any like that?

Comment: I imagine wherever your were, there may not have been enough satellites for the your device to determine a location. I for one would like to know how to handle this, code-wise. Interesting question.

Comment: it's perfectly posible without a data conection on my device anyway.  startup may well be longer e.g. give it at least 120 seconds.  Check with some other apps.

Answer (score 4):

A GPS receiver needs to have several GPS satellites above the horizon, in order to receive the signals it uses to calculate its longitude and latitude.  Each satellite broacasts this ephemeris information as part of its data stream, but a standalone receiver might take several minutes to scan through the available satellite frequencies from a "cold start" (where cached ephemeris information is out of date or incorrect for the current location).

GPS receivers on cell phones often implement "carrier assisted GPS", where the cellular network pushes the up-to-date GPS satellite ephemerides out to the handsets from time to time, so the phone already knows which satellites are in view at any given time/location without having to do a search.

If you don't have cellular network access, your phone might be programmed to fall back to a satellite-by-satellite search for usable signals, and might take longer to get its first GPS fix (if it can get one at all without carrier assistance).

Comment: That's pretty interesting. Thanks for sharing. Do you have more information on phones getting a gps fix without carrier assistence?

Comment: @Stagleton: My standalone GPS receiver can take up to 15 minutes to receive the almanack data from a satellite.  Also, if your remote location was a long way North (or South) you'll find you get to a point where you can't see enough satellites to get a fix.